# Label change color of a word dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I change the color of a word from a `label.Content` ? I mean if I have for example  the following label content:

> Hello cruel world !

How do I change only the color of the word `cruel` ?

Note: I do want to do this by code, `TextRange` doesn't seem to work for my problem.

Comment: is this text dynamically generated ?

Comment: This is not a proper question for stack. You should add in what you have tried. What you have googled. Also, some of your source code is usually helpfull. This is an easy answer also so you should have had any issues googling it.

Comment: Yes, it contains a line from a text file.

Comment: @AMR The only thing I have found was about how to do this on a richtextbox and how to do this via xaml. Also the only function that seem to help me is TextRange but it doesn't work.

Comment: How about using a html control to display the label - create your own custom control, then you can use HTML to colour / bold etc. with ease.

Comment: @harag I have no knowldege about a html control but I'll search about that right away.

Comment: @harag It is WPF, not html

Comment: @Voo apologies, I didn't see the WPF tag and for some reason assumed winforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Label to represent the text, you should use TextBlock instead. Then you can do like this:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello"));
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("cruel") { Foreground = Brushes.Tomato });
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("world !"));
```

Label is a content container control, it means that it is used to show not only text, but something else (images, panels, texts). When you want to show the text only, you should use TextBlock in WPF. This allows you to work with it, as you describe earlier.

If the Label is required anyway, add a container (stackpanel for example) and add a TextBlock into it.

Comment: Thanks, and in place of the hello  `tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello"));` I can add a string variable. Perfect !